# How to invoke JAVA Adapter in IBM MobileFirst 7.0 via application?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Can anyone help with the invocation of Java Adapter in MobileFirst 7.0(Adapter Type in 7.0; not invocation of java class using http adapter)

I have tried

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/XYZ/ABC", WLResourceRequest.GET);
```

But it is not working and it gives a `statuscode 404`. Adapter is deployed and it is available.

Pls help.

Comment: Can you add your adapter code?

Comment: As Yoel mention, you need to provide proper context and code so it could be recreated and better understand what you're doing.

Comment: What happens when you take your URL - `/adapters/XYZ/ABC` - and use it directly in your browser's address bar? If that's a GET, that should work. That will test if your adapter is deployed and listening correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
 var usersUrl = "adapters/UserManagement/users";

 var request = new WLResourceRequest(usersUrl, WLResourceRequest.GET);
```

observe that my URL does not have a leading slash.